# K product array

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am working on an algorithms problem. You have an array numbers, size of array t , number number_of_elements and number multiplication_value. You have to find any set of number_of_elements indexes of the elements of the array , which product will be equal to multiplication_value. It is guaranteed, that such set of indexes exists

That problem looks like 2 sum, but I can't extrapolate it to my case.
I have tried naive algorithm for O(n), but it fails, when you have bad first number in an array. I think there is a way to use recursion in here. I guess it is well-known problem, but I couldn't find the solution

Example in:

```
t = 7
number_of_elements = 2
multiplication_value = 27
numbers = [9,1,1,27,3,27,3]
```

Example out:

```
1 3
```

My code ideas:

```py
    def return_index_values(numbers,multiplication_value,number_of_elements):
    cur_number = int(multiplication_value)
    list_of_indexes = []
    values = []
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if ((cur_number == 1) and (len(values) == number_of_elements)):
            print(values)
            #finishing if everything worked
            break
        else:               
            if (cur_number % int(numbers[i]) == 0):
                if(len(values) < number_of_elements):
            #pushing values if possible
                    values.append(int(numbers[i]))
                    list_of_indexes.append(i)
                    cur_number = int(cur_number / int(numbers[i]))
                    print(cur_number)
                else:
                    pass
            if(len(values) == number_of_elements):
                if mult_check(values,int(multiplication_value)):
               #mult_check checks if the array's element multiplication gives a value
                    break
                else:
               #started dealing with bad cases, but it doesn't work properly
                    values.sort()
                    val_popped = values.pop()
                    cur_number = cur_number * val_popped
```

Bad case for my code

```
 numbers = [9,3,1,27,3,27,3]
```

Comment: @andreee, thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one implementation. Not necessarily the best solution but it gives you some sense of how it can be done.

It first sorts the `numbers` by the element keeping the indices information. Then it performs recursion calls.

```
number_of_elements = 2
multiplication_value = 27
numbers = [9,1,1,27,3,27,3]

def preprocess(numbers, multiplication_value, number_of_elements):
    l = []
    for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
        l.append((num, i))
    return sorted(l, key = lambda tup: tup[0])

def subroutine(numbers, multiplication_value, number_of_elements, idx_start, result):
    if idx_start >= len(numbers):
        return False
    if number_of_elements == 0:
        return True if multiplication_value == 1 else False
    for i in range(idx_start, len(numbers)):
        num = numbers[i][0]
        if num <= multiplication_value:
            if multiplication_value % num == 0:
                idx = numbers[i][1]
                result.append(idx)
                found = subroutine(numbers, multiplication_value / num, number_of_elements - 1, i + 1, result)
                if not found:
                    del result[-1]
                else:
                    return True
        else:
            return False
    return False

result = []
processed_numbers = preprocess(numbers, multiplication_value, number_of_elements)
subroutine(processed_numbers, multiplication_value, number_of_elements, 0, result)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.combinations() (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/itertools-combinations-module-python-print-possible-combinations/) to select number_of_elements entries from your list in all possible ways, then check each whether they multiply to the required number.

Comment: What is the time complexity of it? O(n^2)?

Comment: Since this is combinations, it would be O(n!)